# Saving multiple worksheets as .pdf is causing formula calculation to change to Manual

Tags: excel, pdf, formula

I have an Excel spreadsheet with multiple worksheets in it. I have found that if I save more than one worksheet as a PDF file the formula calculation option setting changes to Manual. If I save a single worksheet as a PDF it remains at Automatic. I need it to remain Automatic as sometimes the figures in the worksheet need to be amended and recalculated.

Any advice on how to get round this?

Comment: At the end of your macro you could set it back to automatic? have you tried that? Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

Comment: Thanks. Already tried that - put it right at the end of the macro to make sure it was after saving as pdf. I thought it was the macro at first that was causing the issue however when testing I manually saved as a pdf and had the same issue.